# Events are not fired when Backbone view rendered using jquery get

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I am getting the entire html code using jquery get() method and setting it on the el of backbone view.The view gets rendered perfectly but the click events i added are not firing. As i am a newbie to backbone i am not able to find the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

The currentTabID is contain the div id on which i want this html to be rendered.

**view.js**

```
var MyFirstView = Backbone.View.extend({

    currentTabID:'',

    initialize:function(){
        this.render();
    },

    render: function (){
        var self = this;
        self.el = self.options.currentTabID;
        $.get('resources/html/myBB.html', function(data) {
            $(self.el).html(_.template(data));
        });
        return this;
    },

    events: {
        'click .savebtnBB': 'invokeME'
      },

    invokeME: function (){
        console.log('Fired');
    }
});
```

Html looks something like below

**myBB.html**

```
<div id="sample_tab">
    <div class="sub-main">
        <form>
        ..
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
        <button class="savebtnBB">click me</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`view.el` is an actual dom element holding the event listeners for your view. You're replacing view's reference to that element with some number and appending the template to some other element.

Your view should act like an isolated unit as much as possible. Your code for appending it to something else should be outside the view, where you're creating it. Your code should look something like the following:

```js
var MyFirstView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    var self = this;
    $.get('resources/html/myBB.html', function(html) {
      self.template = _.template(html);
      this.render();
    });
  },
  events: {
    'click .savebtnBB': 'invokeME'
  },
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template({ /*some data for template*/ }));
  },
  invokeME: function() {
    console.log('Fired');
  }
});

var viewInstance = new MyFirstView();

/*append to whatever you want*/
$(currentTabID).append(viewInstance.el);
```